# I think I hit ctrl z in my blender render?

Tags: rendering, animation

I was rendering a 90 frame animation and  I hit ctrl z by accident but it paused my render and it’s not going anymore. I have no idea how to continue it. Ive hit Ctrl z before and I’ve had to just restart the render because I don’t know how to resume it. It’s just stuck on frame 59 and not moving. I have no idea what ctrl z does in a render. I’m on iMac.

Comment: The only way to resume a Render is if you render image sequences, you just need to select the last frame rendered and continue from there

Comment: How do I select the last frame? I’m a newbie so I don’t know

Answer (score -2):

Was the output format .mp4 or .png?

If it's .mp4 then you can't do anything, you have to re-render the whole animation.

If the output format was .png, then start rendering form where the animation got stuck.

Comment: How do I start the render to where it got stuck?